# Webpage background colour flash

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

Could somebody tell me why this code *doesn't* flash the background colour of my webpage between the two colours.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function blinkit() {
    intrvl = 0;
    for (nTimes = 0; nTimes < 3; nTimes++) {
        intrvl += 1000;
        setTimeout("document.bgColor='#0000FF';", intrvl);
        intrvl += 1000;
        setTimeout("document.bgColor='#FFFFFF';", intrvl);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's working for me in Firefox. Could be because you are not calling the `blinkit()` function?

Comment: where do you call `blinkit` ? All you've shown is the function being defined, not called.

Comment: calling blinkit() in the body

Comment: @user182, can you post your code including the call for blinkit?

Comment: Actually silly me, I wasn't calling it correctly. Working now, but can any of you tell me how I can make the flashing infinite?

Comment: Use the while loop. Just say, `while(1)` because it's going to be forever valid. However, have you considered using CSS3 animation instead?

Comment: Any chance you could post an example of my code with the while loop? Sorry, i'm still a beginner at javascript

Comment: Here is an example of an infinite flasher: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/gbS85/

Comment: why not us CSS for this? http://jsfiddle.net/7KpvE/

Comment: I really hope you are not using this for a production website.

Comment: Got it working, thanks for everyones help. ^^ no I'm not, I'm just playing around learning the magic of webpages :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function blinkit() {
    intrvl = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
        intrvl += 1000;
        setTimeout("document.bgColor='#0000FF';", intrvl);
        intrvl += 1000;
        setTimeout("document.bgColor='#FFFFFF';", intrvl);
    }, intrvl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never pass strings to `setTimeout`, since it's just as bad as `eval`.

Instead, try something like this:

```
function blinkit(times, thenwhat) {
    var toggle = times*2, timer = setInterval(function() {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = toggle%2 ? "#0000FF" : "#FFFFFF";
            toggle--;
            if( !toggle) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                thenwhat && thenwhat();
            }
        },1000);
    return timer;
}
var flashy = blinkit(3);
// The background will flash three times.
// You can also cancel it with `clearInterval(flashy);`
```

With the above code, you can also tell it to do something when it's done:

```
var flashy = blinkit(3,function() {alert("Hello!");});
```